# Return a value from @Composable function to be used as delegate

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-delegate

I have a `Timer()` function to be used as a... timer. A very simple one, it can only be set and its remaining time can be read. No cancel/reset.

I intended to use it as just

```kotlin
var timeLeft by Timer()
```

`timeLeft` here is just an `Int`: write any value to it, the timer starts; read it to know how many seconds are left:

```kotlin
var timeLeft by Timer()

// to start (or restart timer)
timeLeft = 60

// to read time left
CircularProgressIndicator(progress = timeLeft / 60f)
```

This is what I've done so far:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Timer() /* : What? */ {
    var timeLeftSeconds by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    var targetTime by rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(timeLeftSeconds > 0) {
        while (timeLeftSeconds > 0) {
            delay(1000L)
            timeLeftSeconds = (targetTime - currentTimeMillis()).toInt() / 1000
        }
    }

    return /* what? 

        val setValue = { it: Int ->
            timeLeftSeconds = it
            targetTime = currentTimeMillis() + timeLeftSeconds * 1000L
        }

        val getValue = { timeLeftSeconds }

    */
}
```

But I have no idea how to return something that can be used in `by`. Nor the return type signature.

Note that `setValue` has to set also `targetTime`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an object that has a value property.

A `MutableState`, for example, has a value property. You could actually just return the `MutableState` that you already use:

```
@Composable
private fun Timer(): MutableState<Int> {
    val timeLeftSeconds = rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(timeLeftSeconds.intValue > 0) {
        while (timeLeftSeconds.intValue > 0) {
            delay(1000L)
            timeLeftSeconds.intValue--
        }
    }

    return timeLeftSeconds
}
```

Returning State objects from composable functions is bad style, though: State should only be passed down in parameters, not passed up as return values.

There are several alternatives: You could create a new class that represents the internal state of the counter. An instance of that class would then be passed to your `Timer()` function so it can decrease the timer value. This is how a lot of built-in composables also work.

But then again, nothing in your function actually needs compose, so you could just make it a simple class that exposes a value property so that it can be delegated.

One last thing: You start your timer in another composable with `timeLeft = 60`. This will be executed every time a recomposition takes place, so the timer may be reset at arbitrary times. To prevent this you should wrap it in a side effect, like `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll address the "returning State objects from composable functions is bad style" in another comment. Keeping the main design (@Composable with remember + LaunchedEffect etc.) your answer doesn't address the "setValue has to set also targetTime" issue. Earlier I coded the timer without `targetTime` but stepped into 2 problems: 1st the timer took longer (each loop consumed 1000ms + time to process it), and 2nd when the device sleeps the timer is paused and upon resume it will not catch up.

Comment: "Nothing in your function actually needs compose".. well... LaunchedEffect needs. Maybe I could move it elsewhere and retain just the CouroutineScope thing (which I don't master yet). Anyhow I feel that the LaunchedEffect thing is an integral part of the timer. But surely I'll look other ways to code it keeping your advice in mind.

Comment: "Returning State objects from composable functions is bad style" thanks for sharing. I still don't master all of the intricacies of Jetpack Compose but I'm learning a lot. At first I coded everything inside the main screen @Composable function, and that's how the timer got its shape. Upon refactoring I stepped into this issue. Maybe - just maybe - if I rename it to `rememeberTimer` things will become clearer. After all there are a lot of `rememberXXX` built-in returning states (e.G. `rememberScrollState(...): ScrollState`, `rememberRevealState(...): RevealState').

Comment: In compose you can get a `CoroutineScope` by `rememberCoroutineScope()` that you can then pass to your timer class/function. Then you can replace the `LaunchedEffect` with `scope.launch {`.